Interfaces and covariance in PHP
I am attempting to implement a Repository layer in my application. Each Repository will have common methods, such as save() that will accept a specific class.
I started with something like this:
interface Repository {
    public static function save(object $object): bool;
    ...
}

However, when you try and implement this with an actual object, this doesn't work. For example:
class StudentRepository implements Repository {
    public static function save(Student $student): bool {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
$student = new Student();
StudentRepository::save($student);

Leads to the error

Declaration of StudentRepository::save(Student $student): bool must be
compatible with Repository::save(object $object): bool in
/home/user/scripts/code.php on line 9

I've also tried:

extending a class (so the interface becomes save(Entity $entity) and Student extends Entity)
Instantiating the repository layer instead of using static methods
Matching variable names

But none of these make any difference. The only way I could make it work, is when the types of the interface method and the class implementing that matched, which isn't what I'd ideally like here.
I don't understand why a Student $student isn't a Covariance of object $object. Or perhaps it's just that interfaces don't support Covariance (I can't really find any examples that make it clear one way or the other)?
Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php
